# Wrongly junctioned GPIO 1 and GPIO 2

Tags: pi-3b+

I wanted to connect an fan to GPIO 1 and GPIO 6 and what happens is that accidentally GPIO 1 & 2 were junctioned.

I saw an light only and from that moment is not starting.

Anyone has any ide how to repair it, or is definitively dead?
PI 3 MODEL B.

Comment: Could you look at https://pinout.xyz/ `and then edit your question` to make clear which pins were connected.

Comment: If it's not starting anymore after a short, it's almost certainly beyond repair.

Comment: I know the pin numbers. @joan

Comment: How can i test it @DmitryGrigoryev if its repairable ?

Comment: No you don't.  You talked about connecting GPIO.  GPIO numbering has nothing to do with pin numbering.  Connecting GPIO 1 and 2 is  not likely to cause harm.  Connecting pin 1 to pin 2 will destroy the Pi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shorting 3V3 and 5V is fatal. You've successfully burned the power management chip. Same happened to me accidentally. No hope for fixing it, sorry.