# I did a short circuit between the 5v pins

Tags: gpio, boot-issues, rip

I thought I could power a fan by connecting each of its rudimentary wires to pins 2 and 4 (5v pins) on the raspberry. Immediately, the screen the pi was connected to went blank, even though the pi was plugged in.  The PWR (not the ACT) LED stayed on but now the pi won't boot.  Question 1: what is now broken on my pi?  Question 2: can I fix it in any way?
[image: imitation of me connecting the fan to the pi with rudimentary wires]
fan specs:
12 volt DC,
0.15 amps,
1.8 watts

Comment: What you describe shouldn't have caused a problem.  That probably means you did more than you described.  Exactly what did you connect to what?

Comment: Welcome.  It is possible you briefly touched a ground or 3.3V if you did this the way you are in the picture.  In future consider connecting the pins to a breadboard so the contacts are separated better.  BTW, the "rudimentatry wires" of a simple DC device are *power* and *ground*, not power and power (this is a simple process of elimination, since a DC device needs at least those two things to work).  Wiring it up that way would probably just do nothing though, I agree with joan that it shouldn't have damaged the Pi.

Comment: Do you mean pins 2/6 or 4/6 as 2 and 4 are both 5v, with 6 being ground?

Comment: @goldilocks, yeah I probably touched the ground or 3.3v. I guess my answer is basically a combined duplicate of https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/40267/i-short-circuited-5v-gnd-of-rpi and https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/85338/wrongly-junctioned-gpio-1-and-gpio-2.  Thank you for explaining everything to me, as I am a complete beginner with raspberry pi.

Comment: Welcome to the Raspberry Pi flavoured corner of the Stack Exchange network. It sounds like you have gained the dubious honour of a question that can have the [tag:rip]!

Answer (score -2):

[image: GPIO pins] Raspberry Pi GPIO layout shows pins 2 and 4 are 5v and pin 6 is Ground.